# Nested while loops in matrices

Tags: c++

```
bool Is (const vector<vector<int>> &m)
{

bool b = true;
int i=0, j=0;

while (i < m.size() && b==true)
{
    while (j < m[0].size() && b==true)
    {
        if (m[i][j] == 0)
        {
            b=false;
        }
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
return b;
}
```

The problem is, when j terminates, say it becomes 4, it is not reset to 0 while doing the i.

Comment: Well, are you resetting it to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use for loops here ? They allow you to specify an initialization statement, as well as to tie your counter increment logic directly to the loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < m.size() && b; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m[0].size() && b; ++j)
    {
        if (m[i][j] == 0)
        {
            b=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool Is (const vector<vector<int>> &m)
{

bool b = true;
int i=0;

while (i < m.size() && b==true)
{  int j=0; // declare j here
    while (j < m[0].size() && b==true)
    {
        if (m[i][j] == 0)
        {
            b=false;
        }
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use for loop instead of while like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < m.size() && b; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m[0].size() && b; j++)
    {
        if (m[i][j] == 0)
            b=false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an If condition right before starting the i iterations

```
while (i < m.size() && b==true)
{
   while (j < m[0].size() && b==true)
   {
      if (m[i][j] == 0)
      {
          b=false;
      }
      if (j+1<m[0].size() && b==true){
         j++;
      }
      else{
         j = 0;
      }
   }
i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a perfect use case for the *range-based for loop* introduced in C++11, so you don't have to fiddle around with indices:

```
bool b = true;
for (const auto &row : m) {      // or name it column, depending on your layout
    for (auto elem : row) {
        if (elem == 0) {
            b = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!b)
        break;
}
return b;
```